# defining variables in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have many variables in my javascript function and don't fit on one line declaration.

```
var query_string = $('list_form').serialize(), container = $('list_container'),position = container.cumulativeOffset(), layer = $('loaderLayer'),
            remote_url = "/web/view/list_offers.php?" + query_string;
```

is there a way to define these variables on multiple lines with only one

> **var**

keyword?

Comment: I don't know if you can line break a declaration like this, but if you can't, why are you opposed to just writing "var" before each variable?

Comment: I agree. This is disgusting. Just have a line for each declaration, each starting with `var`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var query_string = $('list_form').serialize(),
    container = $('list_container'),
    position = container.cumulativeOffset(),
    layer = $('loaderLayer'),
    remote_url = "/web/view/list_offers.php?" + query_string;
```

If I recall it correctly, that is the pattern advocated by **Doughlas Crackford** to declare multiple variables that script needs.

**Quick Tip:** [Beawere of JavaScript Hoisting :)](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/quick-tip-javascript-hoisting-explained/)

Answer (score 0):

You can seperate declarations by commas:

```
var a, b, c
```

I don't see this often but it's valid.  You can also add the initial values in:

```
var a = 5, b = $('#myDiv').html(), c= 6*43, d = query_string;
```

You really don't see this often, but again it's valid.  I would argue that it's hard to read, and therfore hard to maintain, so you are better off just doing:

```
var a = 5;
var b = $('#myDiv').html();
var c= 6*43;
var d = query_string;
```

Answer (score -1):

Declare the variables with out giving any datatype like var as below.

query_string== $('list_form').serialize();
container = $('list_container');
position = container.cumulativeOffset();
layer = $('loaderLayer');
remote_url = "/web/view/list_offers.php?" + query_string;

it will work.

Comment: ... and play havoc with your scoping